# How can I bind a specific nested list value in a ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a json that I have deserialized.  I have a listview that is bound to the rootobject class.

```
public class Thumbnails
{
    public string mini { get; set; }
    public string webimage { get; set; }

}

public class RootObject
{
    public string userCreated { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<string> property_product { get; set; }
    public Thumbnails thumbnails { get; set; }
}
```

I have bound my list to a listview

```
private void BindListView()
{
    lstView.DataSource = myList;
    lstView.DataBind();
}
```

But I need to display only the webimage value from Thumbnails.  I'm at a loss on how to do that.  It displays the others just fine until I try to add the webimage.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <td>
        <%# Eval("webimage") %>  
    </td>
    <td>
        <%# Eval("id") %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%# Eval("name") %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%# Eval("property_product") %>
    </td>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide the path of the nested class. Checking for `null` is not needed, as long as you are not going to use `.ToString()` etc.

```
<%# Eval("thumbnails.webimage") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a dot notation should help here:

```
<%# Eval("thumbnails.webimage") %>
```

Or you could cast the object to Thumbnails and use its property:

```
<%# ((Thumbnails)Eval("thumbnails")).webimage %>
```

Of course be wary of nulls in both cases.